# Removing Event Listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have problem with removing eventListeners. There is a code:

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName("check");

function mouseoverse (counter) {
    return function mouseoverse () {
        check[counter].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

function mouseouts(counter) {

    return function () {
        check[counter].style.backgroundColor = "white";

}
} 

function clickn(counter) {

    return function () {
        check[counter].removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverse, false)
        check[counter].removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseouts, false)

    }
}


for (var counter1 = 0; counter1 < check.length; counter1++) {
    check[counter1].addEventListener("click", clickn(counter1));
    check[counter1].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverse(counter1));
    check[counter1].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseouts(counter1));
}
```

Honestly, I don't know how to make this work. Any help and explanation what I'm doing wrong would be nice . 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention the nature of the problem. What exactly "doesn't work"? Are there errors in the browser console? Does *anything* happen? How are you including the code on the page?

Comment: `mouseoverse` is not the same thing as `mouseoverse(counter1)`. Just pass the functions themselves (e.g. `mouseoverse`) and replace `check[counter]` with `this` without wrapping everything in other functions.

Comment: @Kage Read Pointy’s comment again. “is not working” is not a problem description.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Answer (score 2):

The `.removeEventListener()` method only works when the function you pass in is **exactly** the same function object as one assigned via `addEventListener()`. In your case, there are 2 problems:

1. You're trying to do the removal with references to functions that **build** your event listeners, and not the listeners themselves.
2. You don't save the event listener functions you construct, at least not according to the code you posted, so you'll never be able to remove them.

Thus, you need to somehow save the event listener functions you construct for each element, and then use those saved references when you want to remove them.

In my opinion, it would be simpler and cleaner to just use event delegation for all the event handling, and a per-element class or flag attribute to keep track of whether the event handlers should do anything. Handling events is not a serious performance problem in modern browsers, so having event handlers that don't do anything won't be a problem in the vast majority of applications.

Comment: Thanks for explanation for js newbie like me  ;). I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

First, you bound an event handler by invoking `mouseoverse`, which returns the function to be bound, but when you go to remove, you *pass* `mouseoverse` instead of invoke it.

But even if you invoked it when removing, it still would not work because you're not passing the *same* function. Only way to do it with your current solution would be to have an Array of functions that keep each function by index, so that when it comes time to remove, the `counter` can be used to fetch the correct function.

Either way, you don't need all this code. Do as [**@Xufox**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox) wrote, get rid of the functions being returned and bind/unbind the `mouseoverse` function directly. You can get your reference to the element by using `this` or `event.currentTarget` instead of `check[counter]`.

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName("check");

function mouseoverse(event) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function mouseouts(event) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} 

function clickn(event) {
  this.removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverse)
  this.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseouts)
}

for (var counter1 = 0; counter1 < check.length; counter1++) {
    check[counter1].addEventListener("click", clickn);
    check[counter1].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverse);
    check[counter1].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseouts);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for answer. Time to learn about .this ~~ ^^